# Crop Several Images from within and image

Tags: photoshop-script

I am trying to Crop out images within and image.

Technically it's characters, letters and numbers.

The width is 504 and height is 1008.
I think each Character is a block of 24x24 pixels.

I have been trying myself for awhile, but i can't figure out the Cropping.
I haven't gotten as far as being able to automate the entire process cause of that.

Here is my script as it is right now.

```
    hlineMinus = 0;
//for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
imageWidth = activeDocument.width.as('px');
imageHeight = activeDocument.height.as('px');
imageWidth - 24;
imageHeight - 24;

hline = i+1 * 24;
hlineMinus = 0;
if(hline = 21*24)
hlineMinus += hline;
hline=hlineMinus;

    var bounds = [24*(i), 0, 24*(i+1), 24*(i+1)];
    doc.crop(bounds);

    //do the math to figure out how big you want it after resize
    //doc.resizeImage(newWidth, newHeight);

    //note this is saving over the original!!!!
       var opts, file;
        opts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
        opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
        opts.PNG8 = false;
        opts.quality = 100;
var d = i;
        pngFile = new File(doc.path + d + doc.name );
        app.activeDocument.exportDocument(pngFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, opts);
//app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);  
//stepHistoryBack();

//}

function stepHistoryBack(){
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
        var ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID( "HstS" ), charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" ), charIDToTypeID( "Prvs" ));
    desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID( "null" ), ref);
executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "slct" ), desc, DialogModes.NO );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried to test your script with a fixed falue of the `bounds`? It looks like syntax is correct, but the math isn't.